# Xamarin: Default Display Alert background colour doesn't always follow app theme

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, darkmode, displayalert

I have a Xamarin app where I use DisplayAlert() and I have noticed that it, more often than not, will display alerts in light mode, even when I am in dark mode. While debugging, I checked the values of App.Current.UserAppTheme, App.Current.RequestedTheme, AppInfo.RequestedTheme and they were all set to dark, yet my alert still displays in light mode. I don't have access to an IOS device so I'm not sure if this is only happening on Android, but that is what I'm testing with. Has anyone come across this problem and know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I used a combination of these two resources:
[one](https://github.com/jerry08/Woka/blob/master/Woka/Common/ThemeManager.cs) and [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241870/how-to-customize-coloraccent-when-changing-the-the)

In `MainActivity.cs`, I added the override below which forces the android theme to update with a style I added as suggested in the accepted answer of [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241870/how-to-customize-coloraccent-when-changing-the-the). Note: I used `AppInfo.RequestedTheme` instead of `Application.Current.RequestedTheme` as it was usually incorrect in my case.

```
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (Xamarin.Essentials.AppInfo.RequestedTheme == Xamarin.Essentials.AppTheme.Light)
    {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
    }
    else
    {
        this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.NightTheme);
        AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightYes;
    }
}
```